# Flip animating border-right using gsap flip libary

Tags: animation, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit, gsap

I'm currently working on a flip animation using the gsap flip library in my SvelteKit project. The animation is working well, including animating the borders. However, I'm facing an issue with a specific div that only has a right border.

Here's how the div is structured in my code:

```html
<div class="{menuOpen ? 'w-72 border-secondary/25 p-2' : 'w-0 border-secondary/0'} menuAutomation flex w-full overflow-hidden border border-b-0 border-l-0 border-t-0 bg-primary2">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

In addition, here's how my flip function looks like:

```js
const toggleMenu = async () => {
    //state
    const state = Flip.getState(".menuAutomation", {
      props: "borderRadius,border,padding,borderRight",
    });

    //action
    menuOpen = !menuOpen;

    await tick();

    Flip.from(state, {
      duration: 5,
      ease: "power2.out",
      absolute: true,
      onComplete: () => {
        hideMenuButton = false;
      },
    });
  };
```

When I log the state object, it seems to capture the correct values for the border properties.

It's worth mentioning that I'm using Tailwind CSS for my styling, but it hasn't caused any issues in other parts of my application.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!